# Problems in Visual Studio 2010 installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I am trying to install visual Studio 2010, but many problems occurred as shown in the link below  .

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=407975visualSetupProblem.png

This installer works correctly on other PCs. 

These are few lines from the log error file:

```
[10/07/13,23:14:00] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty - Property: {481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-    00C04F8EEBA1} - PropertyName: Disable Error Logging - Value: 0
[10/07/13,23:14:02] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty - Property: {481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-00C04F8EEBA1} - PropertyName: Disable Error Logging - Value: 0
[10/07/13,23:14:10] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: Return type:
[10/07/13,23:14:10] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: NetRtReturnCheck
[10/07/13,23:14:38] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty - Property: {CE6EA7C5-0F0C-4D91-B597-092B82E2128B} - PropertyName: AlreadyInstalled - Value: \Microsoft Application Error Reporting\A higher version of Visual Studio is already installed\VC 9.0 Runtime (x86)\VC 10.0 Runtime (x86)\VC 10.0 Runtime (x64)\Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK Prerequisite
[10/07/13,23:15:58] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Error code -939523550 for this component is not recognized.
[10/07/13,23:15:58] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 returned an unexpected value.
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Application Error Reporting
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : A higher version of Visual Studio is already installed
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : IA64 blocker
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows XP Service Pack 3 is required
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows XP x64 Service Pack 2 is required
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows Vista Service Pack 1 Update Information
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows Imaging Component is required
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows Imaging Component (64-bit) is required
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows 2003 Server Service Pack 2 Update Information
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Windows Installer 3.1 or higher is required.
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : VC 9.0 Runtime (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : VC 10.0 Runtime (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : VC 10.0 Runtime (x64)
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is not installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:01] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is not installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows 2003
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows 2003
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x64)
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x64)
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Vista
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x64) - Vista
[10/07/13,23:16:01] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites     (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:01] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio     2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui:     : Skip : TFS Object Model (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui:     : ROOT : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:02] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:02] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK Prerequisite
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:03] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio     2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86)
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software     Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010     was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU
[10/07/13,23:16:04] VS70pgui: DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:05] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[10/07/13,23:16:05] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[10/07/13,23:16:05] VS70pgui:     : Skip : Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: The error code is 0xc8000222, lots of relevant google hits for that.

Comment: the problem was: The windows update was stopped w when I resume it, and updates took place, the setup worked was successfully completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was: The windows update was stopped w when I resumed it, and updates took place, the setup worked and was successfully completed.